# Xamarin IOS binding

Tags: ios, xamarin, objective-sharpie, xamarin-binding

I am creating binding with Pod , After running Sharpie command i frequently get error regarding , Header not found in the File.  I have checked the file after opening but header was already there. Let me know if anyone face the same issue.
Error Details are below:-

'Realm/Realm.h' file not found
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/private/var/folders/y4/n93ks58x7vd1dl2fr7j9v6mw0000gn/T/com.xamarin.ObjectiveSharpie/11d3f185b30343fe978184fe0a7e4722.h:1:9: fatal error:
could not build module 'MatrixSDK'
@import MatrixSDK;

```
Binding...
846 warnings and 2 errors generated.
Error while processing /private/var/folders/y4/n93ks58x7vd1dl2fr7j9v6mw0000gn/T/com.xamarin.ObjectiveSharpie/11d3f185b30343fe978184fe0a7e4722.h.

Done. Exiting with error code 1.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! From shared error, file can not be found. Do you have a check with this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/cocoapod?context=xamarin/ios)? Maybe it will be helpful. And also can refer to [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=windows) to check where problem is.

Comment: thanks, I had already tried all these.  I am trying to bind Matrix.org SDk . The SDK consist of 6 other libraries.